# Parsing nested JSON using Decodable in Swift

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I'm trying to parse this JSON response

```
    {
    "payload": {
        "bgl_category": [{
            "number": "X",
            "name": "",
            "parent_number": null,
            "id": 48488,
            "description": "Baustellenunterk\u00fcnfte, Container",
            "children_count": 6
        }, {
            "number": "Y",
            "name": "",
            "parent_number": null,
            "id": 49586,
            "description": "Ger\u00e4te f\u00fcr Vermessung, Labor, B\u00fcro, Kommunikation, \u00dcberwachung, K\u00fcche",
            "children_count": 7
        }]
    },
    "meta": {
        "total": 21
    }
}
```

What I'm interested to view in my TableViewCell are only the `number` and `description`

here is what I tried to far:

```
    //MARK: - BGLCats
struct BGLCats: Decodable {

        let meta : Meta!
        let payload : Payload!
        
}

//MARK: - Payload
struct Payload: Decodable {

        let bglCategory : [BglCategory]!
        
}

//MARK: - BglCategory
struct BglCategory: Decodable {

        let descriptionField : String
        let id : Int
        let name : String
        let number : String
        let parentNumber : Int
        
}

//MARK: - Meta
struct Meta: Decodable {

        let total : Int
        
}
```

API request:

```
    fileprivate func getBgls() {
        
        guard let authToken = getAuthToken() else {
            return
        }
        
        let headers  = [
            "content-type" : "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "Accept"       : "application/json",
            "Authorization": "\(authToken)"
        ]
        
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://api-dev.com")! as URL, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        
        let endpoint  = "https://api-dev.com"
        guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            do {
                let BGLList = try JSONDecoder().decode(BglCategory.self, from: data)
                print(BGLList)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.sync { [ weak self] in
                    self?.number = BGLList.number
                    self?.desc   = BGLList.descriptionField
//                    self?.id  = BGLList.id

                    print("Number: \(self?.number ?? "Unknown" )")
                    print("desc: \(self?.desc ?? "Unknown" )")
//                    print("id: \(self?.id ?? 0 )")
                }
            } catch let jsonError {
                print("Error Serializing JSON:", jsonError)
            }
            
       }.resume()
    }
```

But I'm getting error:

```
Error Serializing JSON: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "childrenCount", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"childrenCount\", intValue: nil) (\"childrenCount\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

Comment: The error message doesn't match the JSON and the code. You should get other errors. As you are using *camelCased* names you have to specify at least the `convertFromSnakeCase` strategy and the root object is `BGLCats`. And please: Don't use `NS...` classes if there are native counterparts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

You created the model (mostly) correctly, but there're just two mismatches:

```
struct BglCategory: Decodable {

   let description : String // renamed, to match "description" in JSON
   let parentNum: Int?      // optional, because some values are null
   // ...
}
```

Second issue is that your model properties are **camelCased** whereas JSON is **snake_cased**. JSONDecoder has a `.convertFromSnakeCase` startegy to automatically handle that. You need to set it on the decoder prior to decoding.

Third issue is that you need to decode the root object `BGLCats`, instead of `BglCategory`.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase // set the decoding strategy

let bglCats = try decoder.decode(BGLCats.self, from: data) // decode BGLCats

let blgCategories = bglCats.payload.bglCategory
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JSONDecoder doesn't know that for example `bglCategory`  is represented in JSON payload as `bgl_category`. If the JSON name isn't the same as the variable name you need to implement `CodingKeys` to your `Decodable`

In your case:

```swift
struct BglCategory: Decodable {
  
  let descriptionField : String
  let id : Int
  let name : String
  let number : String
  let parentNumber : Int?
  
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, name, number
    case descriptionField = "description"
    case parentNumber = "parent_number"
  }
}

struct Payload: Decodable {
  
  let bglCategory : [BglCategory]!
  
  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case bglCategory = "bgl_category"
  }
  
}
```